# Weird variable problems in c and assembly

Tags: c, variables, assembly

I have encountered many cases already.

I have a variable let's say `x`. I have unexpected value of `x` though the methods/procedures are right.

I added a variable let's say `y`. I tried to transfer/copy the value of `x` to `y` and made it the variable to be processed.

Variable `x` is now unused. I have a another variable `y` which is used.

It works.

I tried having variables `x` and `y`, didnt use `x` and only processed `y`. It works.

However, if I did removed the variable unused which is `x`, It suddenly fails.

In my cases in assembly, when the variables used are swapped.

```
number      DW  12345
number2     DW  54321
```

to

```
number2     DW  54321
number      DW  12345
```

I get unexpected results on my methods. However, if I retain them, if I don't swap them, there's no problem at all.

can you please explain what's happening?

**EDIT**

sample in c

```
char studno[10],oldstudno[10];

while(fgets(buff, 200, fp) != NULL){

    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = 0;               

    tokenptr = strtok(buff,",");
    while(tokenptr != NULL){

        strcpy(studno,tokenptr);
        tokenptr = strtok(NULL,",");
        strcpy(courseno,tokenptr);

    }

    oldstudno[0] = '\0';
    strcat(oldstudno,studno);
```

}

supposedly, `oldstudno` will have a length of 10, sample value is `9999-99999`
but after the line `strcpy(studno,tokenptr);`, as I check the output,it appends the value of `studno` to `oldstudno`.

When I tried

```
oldstudno[10] = '\0';
```

to cut the appended value (even though `oldstudno` has length of 10), printing `oldstudno` will yield blank.

But when I added a variable `oldstudno2[10]` and used it instead of `oldstudno` while not removing variable `oldstudno`, it works.

Comment: Uh, WTF?  Could you please show the relevant code, and be a bit clearer about the "expected" vs. "actual" results?  ALSO: If you're mixing C and assembly - are you sure you're DISABLING optimization (at least for debugging)?

Comment: not mixing. separate instances

Comment: @FoggyDay added some code

Comment: `buff[strlen(buff)-1] = 0` will misbehave should `buff` be the empty string.

Comment: @Enzo if `number` and `number2` are declared in either the `.data` or `.bss` section of you assembly code, then later the values are accessed or manipulated by offset within the section, swapping the values will cause the failures you describe. You must show the assembly code if you want further help, otherwise we can do no more than speculate.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin speculate is fine :) That was last 2 years though. Dont have the code :(

Comment: @Kaz removing that line doesnt fix the problem. Tried it.

Comment: @Enzo Nobody said that was *the* problem; but it is *a* potential problem. If you want to nuke the trailing newline, you have to check that it's actually there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can continue to speculate, there are a number of pitfalls in the code above where you risk writing beyond the end of your `buff` and each of `studno`, `courseno` and `oldstudno`. To prevent the possible overwrite (and leaving your strings unterminated) you need to test the values before the `strcpy` and if needed limit the copy with `strncpy`. There a many ways to do this, but below is a fairly straightforward method. Note the hardcoded values (e.g. `10`) have been replaced with a simple `#define MAXS 10` to allow simple adjustment if needed later. I didn't have the declarations for `buff` or `courseno` so I just inserted them. Look over/test the changes and let me know if you have issue. I haven't tested, but have reasonable confidence in the approach:

```
#define MAXS 10
#define MAXBUF 200

char buff[MAXBUF] = {0};
char studno[MAXS] = {0};
char courseno[MAXS] = {0};
char oldstudno[MAXS] = {0};

while(fgets(buff, MAXBUF - 1, fp) != NULL){

    /* safely remove trailing newline or character return */
    size_t len = strlen (buff);
    while (len > 0 && (buff[len-1] == '\n' || buff[len-1] == '\r'))
        buff[--len] = 0;

    tokenptr = strtok(buff,",");                    /* first token on ','   */
    while (tokenptr != NULL) {

        size_t slen = strlen (tokenptr);            /* get tokenptr length  */
        if (slen > MAXS - 1) {
            strncpy (studno, MAXS - 1, tokenptr);   /* copy max of 9 char   */
            studno[MAXS - 1] = 0;                   /* null-terminate       */
        }
        else
            strcpy (studno, tokenptr);              /* just copy            */

        if (!(tokenptr = strtok(NULL,",")))         /* get courseno pointer */
            break;
        size_t clen = strlen (tokenptr);            /* get tokenptr length  */
        if (clen > MAXS - 1) {
            strncpy (courseno, MAXS - 1, tokenptr); /* copy max of 9 char   */
            studno[MAXS - 1] = 0;                   /* null-terminate       */
        }
        else
            strcpy (courseno, tokenptr);            /* just copy            */

        if ((slen + strlen (oldstudno)) < MAXS)     /* confirm length OK    */
            strcat(oldstudno,studno);
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: string lengths too great to concatenate.\n");
    }
```